# Vuejs: Cannot set property 'profile_picture' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I'm really confused whats wrong with my code. Can someone tell me what I did wrong here.

```
data() {
    return {
        users: [],
    }
},
methods:{
    moveData(response){
        for(var x=0;x<response.data.data.length; x++){
            this.users[x].profile_picture = response.data.data[x].profile_picture;
            this.users[x].age = response.data.data[x].age;
            this.users[x].intro = response.data.data[x].introMessage;
            this.users[x].name = response.data.data[x].userName;
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log('Users',this.users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error suggests that `this.users[x]` is undefined. the simple solution would be to initialize `this.users[x]` with some empty object just like

```
for(var x=0;x<response.data.data.length; x++){
   this.users[x] = {};
   this.users[x].profile_picture = response.data.data[x].profile_picture;
   this.users[x].age = response.data.data[x].age;
   this.users[x].intro = response.data.data[x].introMessage;
   this.users[x].name = response.data.data[x].userName;
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. Also I've found out I can just use the map method
this.users = response.data.data.map(({profile_picture,age,introMessage,userName})=>({profile_picture,age,intro:introMessage,name:userName}))

Answer (score 1):

As you using `this.users[x]`, it always undefined because your array length is 0. So here one way more you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array to modify the field name and directly assign response to your `users` in `moveData`.

**By use of Map array with spread operator**

```js
const response = [{
  profile_picture: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149452.svg',
  age: 25,
  introMessage: 'Hello',
  userName: 'test105'
}, {
  profile_picture: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149452.svg',
  age: 18,
  introMessage: 'HI',
  userName: 'demo105'
}]

console.log(response.map(({age,profile_picture,...r}) => Object.create({
  age,
  profile_picture,
  name: r.userName,
  intro: r.introMessage
})));
```

**Modification in your code, use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method of array**

```js
const response = {
  data: {
    data: [{
      profile_picture: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149452.svg',
      age: 25,
      introMessage: 'Hello',
      userName: 'test105'
    }, {
      profile_picture: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149452.svg',
      age: 18,
      introMessage: 'HI',
      userName: 'demo105'
    }]
  }
}

let users = [];
for (var x = 0; x < response.data.data.length; x++) {
  users.push({
    profile_picture: response.data.data[x].profile_picture,
    age: response.data.data[x].age,
    intro: response.data.data[x].introMessage,
    name: response.data.data[x].userName
  });
}

console.log(users)
```